# serial stream and defined variables

Tags: c++, printf

Hopefully an easy question from the newb...

If I have a defined variable:

```
#define LOCK_OUT   0xA00A
```

and I use it in a serial stream like this:

```
iprintf("%s Sent to the system. \r\n", LOCK_OUT);
```

on my serial terminal, will I see the text representation of LOCK_OUT or the numeric representation? For instance:

"LOCK_OUT Sent to the system."

in particular, I have a loop that checks an array of defined macros, and I want to use the selected macro (once found) in the output serial stream. so this would be the loop:

```
int UDPDATA;
for (int i = 0, i < UDP_Size; i++)
{
    if (MACRO_ARRAY[i] == UDPDATA iprintf("%s Sent to system \r\n", MACRO_ARRAY[i]); 
}
```

and I want the macro name sent to the serial stream, not the value it represents. I hope I'm explaining this correctly...
vs

"0xA00A Sent to the system."

I'm looking to do the first, not sure if it's possible... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because, macros are substitutions, you would have to do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define LOCK_OUT 0xA00A

int main() {
    // %#04x prints 4 hexadecimal places
    printf("%s %#04x Sent to the system. \r\n", STRINGIFY(LOCK_OUT), LOCK_OUT);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Another queestion arises - say I have a whole bunch of macros defined - and I have an array of these macros as well. MY program searches through the array for the matching macro, then has to output it through the serial port in the same fashion. If I just use STRINGFY(array[i]) in my iprintf statement, I'll get "array[i]" in my serial stream, and not the macro I'm trying to identify... I probably should have asked that question first... lemme edit my post...

Comment: @Jedi I don't think it's possible. Because if you're statically defining the array like `arr = { LOCK_OUT }`, how can the compiler get `LOCK_OUT` when the value is substituted as `0xA00A`?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, what `#define` macro does is pure substitution without semantic parsing.

If you define `LOCK_OUT` as `0xA00A`, the compiler will replace `LOCK_OUT` with `0xA00A` first, and then interprete it as a integer value.